# What is ${\rm Ker} T, \overline{{\rm Ker} T}, {\rm Im} T, \overline{{\rm Im} T}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, analysis

My operator is $T:l^1\rightarrow l^1$, given by $T(x_1.\ldots,x_n,\ldots)=(x_1,\frac{x_2}{2},\ldots,\frac{x_n}{n},\ldots)$ What is ${\rm Ker} T, \overline{{\rm Ker} T}, {\rm Im} T, \overline{{\rm Im} T}$.

Well, here is my attempt

$T$ is continuous because $||T(x_n)||_{l_1}=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}|\frac{x_n}{n}|\leq \sum_{1}^{\infty}|x_n|=||x_n||_{l_1}$ then $||T||\leq1$.

The  $\ker T=\{(x_n):T(x_n)=(0,\ldots,0,\ldots)\}=\{(x_n): \frac{x_k}{k}=0\;\forall k\}=\{(0,0,\ldots)\}=\overline{{\rm Ker} T}$

Now for the ${\rm Im} T$ is more difficult-${\rm Im} T=\{T(x_n):(x_n)\in l_1\}$ then i believe that ${\rm Im} T$ is not all $l_1$ because this implies that $T$ could be surjective, but for $(y_n)\in l_1$ if we suppose that exist $(x_n): T(x_n)=(y_n)$ then $x_n=ny_n$ for all $n$ but $(ny_n)$ does not belong to $l_1$. For this reason i believe that ${\rm Im} T$ is smaller than $l_1$. But what exactly is ${\rm Im} T$. Please, somebody can help me ${\rm Im} T$ and $\overline{{\rm Im} T}$.
Thanks

Best

Comment: $(ny_n)$ might be in $l_1$. It depends on the nature of $y_n$.

Comment: It may also be the case that you’re not expecting to describe the image in any more detail than that. Simply all $(y_n)\in l_1$ such that $(ny_n)$ is also in $l_1$. But, is this space closed?

Comment: Thank you,  you right. I need to find conditions such that $\sum |ny_n|<\infty$

Comment: if i suppose that $\sum |ny_n|<\infty$ then $ny_n\rightarrow 0$ equivalently $|y_n|\leq \frac{\epsilon}{n}$ for all $n\geq N_\epsilon$

Comment: Since it isn’t possible to precisely characterise all elements of $l^1$ I doubt it’s possible to characterise all elements of $\operatorname{Im}(T)$ any more precisely than what you’ve done so far (I could be wrong though). The real question for you is determining whether or not the image is closed.

Comment: thank you again @FShrike!! How can see if this space is closed. By definition i need to take someone in $\overline{Im T}$ and  try to see if it belongs $Im T$?

Comment: The condition is that $\sum_{n}|ny_n| < \infty$. That's a full characterization. You cannot go further with a description because you cannot characterize the sequences $\{ w_n \}$ for which $\sum_{n}|w_n| < \infty$. We just give the condition a name: the sequence is in $\ell^1$. That doesn't really answer the question, but you can't really answer the question.

Comment: Yes that’s one way to check closure. It’s the first way I can think of. Btw I don’t know if it is actually closed, I was just highlighting what it is you need to focus on.